# IronPDF html query parameter

Tags: ironpdf

Does IronPDF support html query parameters, or is there an alternate method?

I've been using IronPDF to convert an html file to PDF using the following method: `var pdf = ironRenderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(reportPath);`

However, the html located at reportPath now requires a parameter userid. I have tried `var pdf = ironRenderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(reportPath?userid=1);` but that gives me the following error: `CheckHtmlFilePath - File not found: .../index.html%3Fuserid=1'`

I can't see any documentation in IronPdf that parameters are supported. Does anyone have any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the parameter to the variable name, add it to the string. For example:

```
reportPath += "?userid=1";
var pdf = ironRenderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(reportPath);
```

Check the URL to see if there is already a parameter, and manipulate the URL string accordingly.  If you posted more code I could have described more.